# Ford Escape 2017 Titanium

Tags: ford, fuel-system

The recommended petrol for Ford Escape 2017 Titanium is minimum Octane 95. However, the previous user has used Octane 91- mileage still less than 2000 km.

Can I now change over to Octane 95 while there is still some Octane 91 left in the tank?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add 95 octane to the tank that has 91 octane in it.

Blending fuel together is harmless. Mid-grade gasoline is typically a blend of lower and higher octane from their respective tanks and mixed at the pump.